# How to call function after observable is ready

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm new in Angular and Observables. My problem is:
in my component HomePage I call service that call http.get  and return an observable. On my template HomePage I use async for this data$. I need to call another void function in ngOnInit that will use data$ when it is returned. So I can not to figured it out how to do this.

HomePage.ts

```js
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  data$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //I need userId that will be returned here
    this.data$ = this.dataService.getMyData(); 
    //how to call this function after data$ is returned?
    this.sendMessage(data.userId);
  }

  sendMessage(data.userId){
     //send this userId 
  }
}
```

HomePage.html

```
<app-homepage form="true" *ngIf="{ data: data$ | async} as myData">
<div *ngIf="data.userId">
///....
```

I've tried this:  but each time I input some data on the page - it calls sendMessage() multiple times...

```js
this.data$ = this.dataService.getMyData().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        this.sendMessage(data.userId);
        console.log("in pipe")//here I see multiple calls when I click on checkbox for exemple..
      }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
this.data$ = this.dataService.getMyData().pipe(
  take(1),
  tap((data) => {
    this.sendMessage(data.userId);
    console.log("in pipe")//here I see multiple calls when I click on checkbox for exemple..  
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your service is returning an `Observable`, then you need to `subscribe` to it in order to read what the response is, like this:

```js
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  // data$: Observable<any>;
  theResult: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.dataService.getMyData().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('See your response', response);
      theResult = response.userId;
      this.sendMessage(theResult);
    });
  }

  sendMessage(data.userId){
     //send this userId 
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that, when you `subscribe` to an Observable, that is an `asynchronous` operation, that is why, after you get the `response` in the `subscribe` step, you will need to call your other function.

Comment: I subscribe with async pipe in my template, so I don’t want to subscribe again